# How to add a remote repository to my own git repository

Tags: git, github, phalcon

I have have my own git repository with some subfolders which all belong to my git repository. Now I want to add another subfolder `vendor` that I cloned from a remote github url.

However, When I try to commit the new folder `vendor` and its contents,(subfolders, files, etc),  git tells me that there are no changes, and I don't know how to add this new subfolder `vendor`.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken with my answer. Can you please list all the git commands in sequence (including in which working directory you were) that you used?

Comment: Generally, [`vendor/` *should not* be versioned](https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md). It is usually generated from `composer.json` and `composer.lock`. Do you have a good reason to include `vendor/` in your repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is that you have a git repository in which resides another repository. I don't know why, but sometimes git silently ignores subdirectories which are git repositories themselves.

The cleanest way to do proceed is to add the subfolder `vendor` as a git **submodule**. You do this by

```
git submodule add ./vendor
```

in your parent git repo after having cloned the vendor repo (that's where you are now). Explaining submodules would be out of scope for a simple post. However, you can think of it as a pointer to the remote `vendor` repository that other people can use to obtain a full working copy of your workdir tree. Please refer to

```
git help submodule
```

for details.

Comment: Thanks!, i try with  git submodule add vendor, but, response error: URL de repo: «vendor» debe ser absoluto o empezar con ./|../

Comment: Sorry, that was my error. You have to add ./ to vendor (i.e. ./vendor)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, it might help

```
git status
git add
git commit
git push
```